# Create widgets based on user input, in the .kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to ask the user for a number, then display that amount of widgets.

This is how I do it:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return List()


class List(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(List, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1


        user_input = 3 # Just an example
        for i in range(user_input):
            label = Label(text="Widget number {}:".format(i + 1))
            self.add_widget(label)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

**The problem is:** the point of "kivy language" is to keep the logic in the `.py` file, and the design in the `.kv` file.

Is there any way I can keep the design only in `.kv` file, while doing this (having a `for` loop)?

(I'm new to kivy, sorry if I'm asking a simple question. :) )

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, you can.

The KV file is used primarily to design the looks while the login part of a program is handled by the PY file.

**.kv file**

```
<classname>:
    Button:
        text:'click me'
        on_release: root.function_to_call_from_py_file()
```

**.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class List(GridLayout):

    def function_to_call_from_py_file(self):
        print('This function is called')


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return List()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: you can add the for loop in the function

Comment: It's a `for` loop that displays widgets. if the `for` loop is in the function, my widgets (design) must be in the function too.

Comment: give an id to the layout in kv file....  and use the add_widget option in the for loop to dynamically add widgets

Comment: So in the `.kv` file I only make that widget once? I'll try that.

Comment: yes, you only make the layout in the kv, and add the widgets from the for loop in the py file